# Concatenate cells flexibly

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I have a structure **P** with various numbers of cells. For instance, **P.Block1.onsets**, **P.Block2.onsets**, **P.Block3.onsets**, **P.Block4.onsets**, etc. Onsets are **1x16** cells (i.e., there are 16 cells), each cell contains 1x4 double. So P.Block1.onsets{1,2} could be something like this [12, 37, 108, 226]. P only contains field BlockX and nothing else. Blocks are structures and only contain field 'onsets' and nothing else. I would like to concatenate all the onsets cells. I could do something like this:

```
all_onsets=vertcat(P.Block1.onsets,P.Block2.onsets,P.Block3.onsets,P.Block4.onsets);
```

However, the number of blocks are variables, sometimes, say I have 4, other times I might have 6 or 8. Is there any way I can do the vertcat flexibly? The output all_onsets should be nx1 with n being 16 x no. of blocks. I hope this makes sense.

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post input sample dimensions and what you're expecting on the output?

Comment: or are you planning to fill in the missing dimensions using some default value?

Comment: Sorry, I have clarified the question a bit more. I'm not looking to fill missing dimensions with any default value. all_onsets output should have variable dimensions, depending on how many blocks there are.

Comment: 1x16 cells or a cell element that is 1x16 doubles/int?

Comment: Does your structure **only** contain fields of `BlockX` where `X` is a number, or are there other fields as well?

Comment: @A.Rainer Perhaps a bit of code to reconstruct random data with your stucture would help

Comment: @rayryeng This is why I hate referencing sequential struct elements for readability XD

Comment: @A.Rainer Also how big are the blocks? Or are they just objects/structs themselves?

Comment: @A.Rainer Can you clarify, do you want all onsets then `vertcat`ed into matrices or cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of structs to get rid of `Block*` fields and then reference the `onsets` field in resulting aray to get a comma-separated list and use `vertcat`:

```
Q = structfun(@deal, P);
all_onsets = vertcat(Q.onsets);
```

Comment: Learned something new today: structfun. Thank you so much!

Comment: @A.Rainer, no problem. `cellfun` and `arrayfun` get a lot of exposure but `structfun` is not that often mentioned in solutions on SO.

Comment: Nice. I always forget about `structfun`

Answer (score 3):

If all of the field names begin with `Block`, then you can dynamically extract all of the field names using the [`fieldnames`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) function, then we can loop through each of the fields, access the `onsets` nested field and concatenate our results:

```
names = fieldnames(P);
all_onsets = [];
for idx = 1 : numel(names)
    all_onsets = vertcat(all_onsets, P.(names{idx}).onsets);
end
```

The first line of code extracts all of the field names and stores them into a cell array.  Next, we initialize `all_onsets` to be an empty array, then for each field name in your structure, we get the field whose name starts with `Block`, then access the `onsets` nested field and concatenate this to `all_onsets`.  Take special note of the way I'm accessing `P`.  We can create **dynamic** strings that coincide with the field you want.  In the end, we will have concatenated all `onsets` subfield matrices into one large cell array.

The result of `all_onsets` will look like this:

```
>> all_onsets
all_onsets = 
    [1x4 double]
    [1x4 double]
    [1x4 double]
    [1x4 double]
    ...
```

Comment: Sigh...I can keep creating my vectorized code to make it faster (should be) and have less lines, but I don't think these guys will choose my answers :( +1 for a working solution too

Comment: @krisdestruction - Ah yeah lol.  That's how I feel like with Luis Mendo and Divakar... no matter what I do, they always find faster and more efficient solutions.  As such, I often venture into topics where they're not experts :P That how I have a leg up.  However, if it's a valid approach and unique, then that's all that really matters.  The answer being accepted is of little consequence.... as long as you put an answer forward :).  Answers here are for longevity and there is more than one way to skin a cat!

Comment: True, it's just when I look at some StackOverflow code, I just see new users not taking advantage of vectorization and that makes me sad. Quick Q since I can't seem to see it in the OP's question. Did the OP want it as a cell or as a matrix?

Comment: @krisdestruction - I'm actually not sure... the code that the OP posted is what I went with.  I just generalized it so that a `for` loop is used.  I'm actually unclear on what the desired output is.

Comment: @krisdestruction - Yes I agree.  I've seen many of those answers.  The best way to discourage those kinds of answers is to not vote on them.  If no one votes on them.... or if there are negative votes, then the person who provided that answer will take the hint and think to themselves that the method is probably not the best way to go about things.  However, there are situations where a `for` loop is certainly merited... but for things like indexing, `for` loops are unnecessary.

Comment: Ah I guess he selected your solution, I'll change my answer accordingly.

Comment: @rayryeng This works great. I'll make sure to use fieldnames more from now on.

Comment: @rayryeng Woah I just realized, struct/fieldnames will **not** store the order of the fields as they are alphabetically, but the order they were initialized in!

Comment: @krisdestruction - Please ask me before you edit my post to ensure that I agree with your changes.  In this case, the output is fine, but please do that next time.

Comment: Ah will do. I though answer edits ask/suggests the OP though. Sorry it's only the first time I've really used this feature

Comment: @krisdestruction - No worries man.  Yeah I got a notification on the suggested edit, but I was sleeping when that happened.... so what happens is that other people who have the privilege to review edits can approve it and other people decided to approve it lol.  It's fine and I'm glad you showed the output... but yeah if you can do me a favour and just ask me next time that'd be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Oh gotcha didn't know that would happen haha. Okay will do that/comment next time!

Answer (score 1):

First create some fake data.

```
P.Block1.onsets = {[1, 37, 108, 226] [2, 37, 108, 226]}';
P.Block2.onsets = {[3, 37, 108, 226] [4, 37, 108, 226]}';
```

Then change P's fields (all those blocks) into a cell.

```
P = struct2cell( P );
```

Then you can convert each block's onsets into a matrix using `cellfun`. Your output will be a vertical cell of nx4 matrices. You need `cell2mat` to concatenate and transform them into a matrix.

```
A = cell2mat( cellfun( @(C) cell2mat( C.onsets ), P, 'UniformOutput', false ) );
```

My code generates the following output.

```
cellfun =>
    [2x4 double]
    [2x4 double]
>> cell2mat(A)
ans =
     1    37   108   226
     2    37   108   226
     3    37   108   226
     4    37   108   226
```

If you want to convert the matrix to cells, you can use my [rows2cell.m function](http://pastebin.com/KkpVshAE).

Comment: ... and so starts the battle between cells and structures :P +1.

Comment: yup lol, but you can see that I can still remove the structs really easily and cell operations are straightforward :D

Comment: actually I might have misunderstood the question's outputs, let me double check

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't mention in my question the first time (my apologies) but I have revised it to state that the desired output should be nx1 with n being 16 x number of blocks. This is because I want to preserve the order of elements in each onsets cell.

Comment: Well this preserves the order of the blocks too, it's just it's converted into a matrix instead of keeping it as a cell like in @rayryeng's output. Any preference whether you want a matrix or cell?

Comment: Note that block 1 has 1 and 2 as the first element, and block 2 has 3 and 4 as the first element and that is fully preserved in my matrix

Comment: Ah. I got it! matrix is preferred.

Comment: The other answers aren't matrices so only this will create the output you want! However to convert from a cell to matrix, all you need to run is `cell2mat`.